# java.time.Instant -> java.sql.Timestamp behaving differently on Windows vs *nix (timezone-related)

Tags: java, hibernate, timestamp, jodatime, java-time

Somewhere in the code I have `Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(instant);` where instant is, as the name suggests, `java.time.Instant`. (Why? To allow Hibernate 4.x to persist, via a `UserType`, JDK8 time types, not yet supported before Hibernate 5).

In fact, let me put the code so it's clear. The log statement is for this problem.

```
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (value != null){
        Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from((Instant) value);
        log.info("nullSafeSet from " + value + " (as long: " + ((Instant) value).toEpochMilli() + ") to " + ts + " (as long: " + ts.getTime() + ")");
        StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP.nullSafeSet(st, ts, index, session);
    } else {
        st.setNull(index, Types.TIMESTAMP);
    }
}
```

And here's the problem. On Windows (7, 64-bit although it shouldn't matter) the string representation of the Timestamp corresponds to the UTC value.

```
From: 2015-05-12T19:00:08.191Z (as long: 1431457208191) 
  to: 2015-05-12 19:00:08.191  (as long: 1431457208191)
```

On *nix (Linux, OS X), the string representation corresponds to the local (EST, or EDT to be precise)  time:

```
From: 2015-05-12T19:16:54.488Z (as long: 1431458214488) 
  to: 2015-05-12 15:16:54.488  (as long: 1431458214488)
```

The absolute times are the same as it can be seen. The problem is that what the JDBC driver sends to an Oracle database into a TIMESTAMP field is *the string representation or an equivalent* (I looked at the network traffic, the parameter is in binary format so it's not easy to figure out exactly what gets sent). *The same code inserts the UTC equivalent of the time when executed from Windows and the local time when executed from Unix.*

I already checked the `user.timezone` system property, it's `America/New York` in both cases. Also the machines themselves are so. Same JDK8 version, same app server, same code.

I'm puzzled by the behaviour and how to fix it.

Comment: Print the value of TimeZone.getDefault(): you'll probably have a different value.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, indeed it is so! Unclear yet why, but at least I have the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, eventually I tracked the cause down and it's different than what I thought. Thanks to @JBNizet for the tip that sent me on the right path.

As mentioned in the comment, by the time the particular method got executed, one one system `TimeZone.getDefault()` was returning "`UTC`" on Windows and "`America/New York`" on the Unix machine. Even though both systems started with `user.timezone="America/New York"`, confirmed by logging.

The real cause was that on the Windows machine, I also had a different web application deployed in the same server. That application, written in Grails, was calling `TimeZone.setDefault("UTC")`, thus overriding, *at JVM level,* the time zone set via the property in my app. I confirmed this with a breakpoint in `TimeZone.setDefault()`.